# Using MVC, how can I show or hide elements based on a checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to learn how to use MVC, and something I want to be able to do is have the user check a box to show or uncheck to hide any number of elements.
I have seen this done where the whole page does not refresh and the user does not need to click any "submit" button, but it does it live.
All the tutorials for MVC I found in my search do not seem to answer this question, or even give me a proper idea of partial views (which I think might be the solution). I understand this question is silly, but I have been looking for a couple hours and can not figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this kind of action without a page refresh you need to use javascript or jQuery

let's say your view looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
<div id="ShowHideMe">
   <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

you need something like,

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#myCheckbox').change(function() {
       $('#ShowHideMe').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
     });
  });
</script>
```

You use javascript, whenever you wanna do client-side programming.

Comment: This is perfect for me, to set the initial state div hidden and the checkbox unchecked i added the  style="display: none;" on the div

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen this done where the whole page does not refresh and the user does not need to click any "submit" button, but it does it live

You are describing javascript, not any built in functionality of (presumably, asp.net)mvc

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery.

$("#myCheckbox").click(function () { $("#someOtherElementId").hide(); });